# How to convert HTML tag into string using python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have my html content as:

```
html = <div>new notes</div><div><ol><li>kssd</li></ol><ul><li>cds</li><li>dsdsk</li></ul><font color=\"#66717b\">ndsmnd</font></div>
```

When I convert the above expression to string, it throws error

```
html_str = str(html)
```

I can see the " are already escaped here. do I need to replace /" with //" and then convert to string?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use **get_text()**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
htmlvar = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(htmlvar.get_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())

tag = soup.html

string = str(tag)

print(string)
```